# Issue with storing values in array without clearing previous one on button click

Tags: angular

can someone look into this? I need to store the data in an object on button click. Then that has to be displayed on the view. Again if the user selects some other value in the dropdown and enter data in text box, on the button click, 
again the data needs to be stored in the same object without clearing the previously stored value.

Right now I am able to store the vaue in an object and display it. But the problem I have is, it is storing the same value two times in a button click. And if I select another value, the previous value is being overridden by new value
but the array size is being increased without getting cleared.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is my HTML file.

```
    <md-select [placeholder]="result" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemType">
    <md-option *ngFor='let attr of result' [value]="attr.fieldType" ng-selected="attr.fieldType"> {{attr.attribute}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItemType =='string' || selectedItemType =='decimal' || selectedItemType == 'text' || selectedItemType == 'integer'">
    <input placeholder="Enter Text" type="text" class="input" [(ngModel)]="txtEntered">
  </div>
 <button *ngIf="selectedItemType" md-raised-button (click)= "Add()" color="accent" >Add</button>
  <span *ngFor='let selVal of finalValues'> {{selVal.attributeName}} {{selVal.value}}
  </span>
```

here is my typescript class

```
export class test{
Add() {
  this.addToList();
  }

addToList() {
  this.addValues.push(this.selectedItemType, this.txtEntered);
  this.finalValues = this.addValues.map(({attributeName, value}) =>
  new SelectedList(this.selectedItemType, this.txtEntered));
}
}
```

Here is my model class

```
export class SelectedList {
    constructor(
        public attributeName: any,
        public value: any
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to `push` like this instead in `addToList()`?

```
this.addValues.push({ attributeName: this.selectedItemType, value: this.txtEntered });
this.finalValues = this.addValues.map((mapElem: {attributeName, value}) =>
 new SelectedList(mapElem['attributeName'], mapElem['value']));
```

Also, if you are in the realms of angular 2 or higher, then I don't think the usage of `ng-selected` is valid. You should use `selected` instead (`[selected]` if you are assigning dynamically).

Comment: I was trying to assign the values in of selectedItemType and txtEntered to an object. What I need is, I need to store those values when ever the user clicks button. Then need to display the vaues in the UI using some list. If user selects another value and clicks button again, then I should be able to add the new value as well without removing the previous value.

Comment: Updated my answer. See if that is something close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like amal has a perfectly functioning answer, so you can definitely go with that. In addition, [here's a working plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/EbS75N?p=info) that does essentially what he was pointing out, though it feels like you can definitely skip `this.addValues` entirely, since what you want in the end is an `Array<SelectedList>`

The relevant code from the plunk:

```
Add() {
     this.addToList();
}

addToList() {
    this.finalValues.push(new SelectedList(this.selectedItemType, this.txtEntered));
}
```